# Class api does not exist Reflection Exception on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, dingo-api

I removed Dingo/api from my laravel 5.4 project.

1. Removed from composer.
2. created new Routes file
3. removed References for Dingo in `RouteServiceProvider`
4. Removed Dingo Service Provider from `config/app.php`

However when I call an endpoint, getting this error

> ReflectionException.. Class api does not exist
>   in Container.php line 729

My config\app.php

```
    <?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Version
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the version of your application. This value is used when
    | the framework needs to place the application's version in a notification
    | or any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    */

    'version' => '1.5.159',

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug'           => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url'             => 'http://localhost',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone'        => 'UTC',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale'          => 'en',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Application Supported Locale
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | The supported locale determines the locale to use across the application.
   | This is used in localization middleware.
   |
   */

    'supported_locale'  => ['en', 'ar'],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key'             => env('APP_KEY', 'test'),
    'cipher'          => 'AES-256-CBC',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    /*those options are overriden in bootstrap/app for info.log and error.log*/
    'log'             => 'daily',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | MaxMind mmdb Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you specify the path to MaxMind GeoLite2-City.mmdb
    |
    |
    */
    'maxmindDB'             => env('APP_MAX_MIND_MMDB', "./maxmind/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers'       => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TranslationProvider::class,

        App\Providers\ResponseMacroServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,

        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,

        Phaza\LaravelPostgis\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,

        Jenssegers\Raven\RavenServiceProvider::class,
        Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider::class,
        Vinkla\Algolia\AlgoliaServiceProvider::class,
        GoogleMaps\ServiceProvider\GoogleMapsServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\PubNubServiceProvider::class,
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
        Maknz\Slack\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,
        Wilgucki\Csv\CsvServiceProvider::class,
        Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
        Waavi\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        /**
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
        Superbalist\Zendesk\ZendeskServiceProvider::class,
        BaoPham\DynamoDb\DynamoDbServiceProvider::class,

        /**
         * Toters Packages Service Providers...
         */
        Toters\DistanceCalc\DistanceCalcServiceProvider::class,

    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases'         => [

        'App'              => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus'              => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'               => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'         => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Input'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
        'Inspiring'        => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
        'Lang'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'              => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'            => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'              => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'             => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Notification'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'JWTAuth'          => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
        'PushNotification' => Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\Facades\PushNotification::class,
        'Algolia'          => Vinkla\Algolia\Facades\Algolia::class,
        'GoogleMaps'       => GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade::class,
        'Image'            => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
        'Slack'            => Maknz\Slack\Laravel\Facade::class,
        'Raven'            => Jenssegers\Raven\Facades\Raven::class,
        'Socialite'        => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
        'PDF'              => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
        'Translate'        => App\Facades\Translate::class,
        'Excel'            => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
        'Zendesk'          => Superbalist\Zendesk\ZendeskFacade::class,
        'TranslationCache' => \Waavi\Translation\Facades\TranslationCache::class,
        'Distance'         => Toters\DistanceCalc\Facades\Distance::class,
    ],

];
```

And this is my route mapping in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
  /**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Comment: can you show me the  `config/app.php` code

Comment: updated my code @UdhavSarvaiya

Comment: Run `composer dumpautoload`, and look for any lingering instances by running `grep -iR dingo *` from the project root

Comment: Aynber's answer was correct for in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Same as me, I fixed it. Look for `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

add the `api` key to the array `$middlewareGroups`.

```php
/**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // 'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```